# How and when using 'ALL' in imap_search

Tags: php, imap

I'm on my way learning IMAP using PHP.
Right now, I'm learning imap_search function.

I have question specifically on `ALL` criteria.

I'm using it like this:

```
$emails = imap_search ( $mailbox, 'BODY "lamaran"' );
$emails = imap_search ( $mailbox, 'ALL BODY "lamaran"' );
```

I got the same result using both line.

My Question is:

- Am I doing it wrong?
- If it's wrong, what is the proper way of using `ALL`?

Answer (score 0):

`ALL` is basically a no-op as an IMAP `SEARCH` criterion.  In general, you won't want to use it unless it's your only criterion and you want your search to return all the items in the selected mailbox.  That's not a joke:

```
A001 UID SEARCH ALL
```

will list the UIDs of all the messages in the mailbox in a much more concise format than

```
A002 FETCH 1:* (UID)
```